# MediaWiki: How to create a "ready in advance" structure for all webpages?

Tags: mediawiki

There is a certain MediaWiki syntax structure I generally use for web pages.
It's not a MediaWiki template; it's just a syntax structure I could copy-paste from a file into the **edit-page** of a certain MediaWiki web page.

Copy-pasting as described isn't very efficient.

How could I reach a state were all new pages I create (that is, the **edit-page** of each one of them) will have the structure I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Creating_pages_with_preloaded_text

You can either:

- Use an extension. See list at the page or to name a few: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BoilerRoom https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultiBoilerplate https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Preloader
- Build your own extension, modifying the php.
- Use a special button or URL to create pages. Preloading can be done with a preload parameter in a URL like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Main_Page?action=edit&section=new&preload=Template:Foo which links to the edit box of a new page, preloaded with Template:Foo. There are also a number of extensions available to trigger your preload file..

Comment: At least for now I decided to go on a third solution which is less automative but is more minimal (I avoid extensions as much as I can for various personal reasons): I just aim to copy paste a template from desktop notes (one should also backup such template). Thank you.